# Can't get Makefile with variables to work

Tags: makefile

I have a makefile and I am trying to get a command to run conditionally in a target.

If I do this:

```
namespace: ## create the kubernetes namespace
K_DESC := $(shell kubectl describe namespace $(KUBE_NAMESPACE) > /dev/null ; echo $$?);
ifneq ($(K_DESC),0)
    kubectl create namespace $(KUBE_NAMESPACE)
else
    kubectl describe namespace $(KUBE_NAMESPACE)
endif
```

I get the error: `Makefile:53: *** recipe commences before first target.  Stop.`

While if I do this:

```
namespace: ## create the kubernetes namespace
    K_DESC := $(shell kubectl describe namespace $(KUBE_NAMESPACE) > /dev/null ; echo $$?);
ifneq ($(K_DESC),0)
    kubectl create namespace $(KUBE_NAMESPACE)
else
    kubectl describe namespace $(KUBE_NAMESPACE)
endif
```

I get the error: `K_DESC := 0;
/bin/sh: 1: K_DESC: not found
Makefile:51: recipe for target 'namespace' failed
make: *** [namespace] Error 127`

Don't know what else to try, trying to fix one problem messes the other.

Comment: I think you need to describe more clearly what you're trying to do...   Are you expecting the code to to run as part of the recipe (when the target is invoked), or as part of the makefile, when the makefile is read?    Makefile recipes are shell scripts, in which case you need to rewrite your code in shell syntax.   If you're trying to do this in make context (when make first reads the file), then what exactly are you trying to do associating it with a target?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you actually want to do is execute a command conditionally, this will do it:

```
namespace:
    if ./$(SCRIPT) > /dev/null ; \
  then kubectl describe namespace $(KUBE_NAMESPACE) ; \
  else kubectl create namespace $(KUBE_NAMESPACE); \
  fi
```

(Note that the whitespace preceding "if" is a tab; all other whitespace is spaces. And the line breaks aren't strictly necessary, I put them in to make the recipe readable.)

If what you actually want to do is assign a value to a variable and then branch on it, all within a recipe, this will do it:

```
namespace9:
    kubectl describe namespace $(KUBE_NAMESPACE) > /dev/null ; \
  K_DESC=$$?; \
  if [ $$K_DESC -eq 0 ] ; \
  then kubectl describe namespace $(KUBE_NAMESPACE) ; \
  else kubectl create namespace $(KUBE_NAMESPACE); \
  fi
```

Comment: I don't understand what is the `$(SCRIPT)` variable here.

Comment: Got it to work with the 2nd example. Just had to add `2>&1` becoming `/dev/null 2>&1` in order to remove the error message.

Comment: @jbssm: Sorry! The `$(SCRIPT)` was careless editing on my part. I was using it as a stand-in for `kubectl describe namespace $(KUBE_NAMESPACE)` in my testing, and forgot to swap back. But all's well that ends well.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do variable assignments in a make recipe body. Try this order of things:

```
K_DESC := $(shell kubectl describe namespace $(KUBE_NAMESPACE) > /dev/null ; echo $$?)

namespace: ## create the kubernetes namespace
ifneq ($(K_DESC),0)
    kubectl create namespace $(KUBE_NAMESPACE)
else
    kubectl describe namespace $(KUBE_NAMESPACE)
endif
```

The "recipe commences before the first target" occurs because GNU Make thinks that these two lines are actually two rules:

```
namespace: ## create the kubernetes namespace
K_DESC := $(shell kubectl describe namespace $(KUBE_NAMESPACE) > /dev/null ; echo $$?)
```

That is, it thinks that you have an empty rule `namespace:` with no build recipe, followed by another rule whose target is `K_DESC`.

Also, if `namespace` isn't an actual file, it should be marked as a phony target:

```
.PHONY: namespace  # somewhere above the namespace: rule
```

Otherwise Make is actually looking for a file called `namespace`. If you do `touch namespace`, then `make namespace` will stop working, because the file exists!

Comment: Keep in mind that with this solution, `K_DESC` will be set at makefile read time -- not when the `namespace:` target is invoked.   If you have any other recipes that might effect the output of `kubectl ...`, then they will not be reflected in `K_DESC` even if they are run before the `namespace` target.

Comment: @HardcoreHenry I'm not going to attempt to solve the real problem here; treating the generation of some Kubernetes namespace as a Makefile target. I'm assuming that this is just a gadget to be able to do `make namespace` (the common anti-pattern of `make` being used to provide a  command language via a vocabulary of targets).

Comment: It's not true that make thinks the first two lines are both rules.  It parses the first line as a rule, `namespace:`, followed by the next line which is a variable assignment `K_DESC := ...`.  However, you can't intermix make recipe lines and make variable assignments.  As soon as make sees the FIRST _non-recipe_ line after a target, that rcipe is over and no more recipe lines can be added to it.  Your solution of course is correct: move the variable assignment to before the beginning of the rule.

Answer (score -2):

There's a bunch of things wrong here:

First, if you type `K_DESC := blah` on your command line it will give you the error `K_DESC: not found`.   This is because bash does not use spaces in assignments -- or use `:=` (it assumes that `K_DESC` is a program name, and that `:=` and `blah` are parameters).   Next, this line sets the *shell* variable `K_DESC` -- not the makefile variable.   This means that the `ifneq`, which is a *makefile* construct, does not know about the value you set in the shell (plus there's some timing issues, as the `ifneq` will be run at makefile read time, long before your recipe is run, so it wouldn't help you anyways).

To add to this, the value that is assigned is assigned in the particular shell instance that runs the first line of the recipe.   Thus, when the first line ends, that shell exits, and the variable is forgotten (it is not known by the shell instance that runs the second line).

And then, you're calling `$(shell command)` -- because there's a single `$`, make will assume it's a make function and expand this at read time.   Instead you want to do `$$(command ...)`.  Make will convert the `$$` to `$`, and pass that to the shell instance along with the command you want to run.

So... to do what you want to do, you likely want:

```
namespace:
    K_DESC=$$(kubectl describe namespace $(KUBE_NAMESPACE) > /dev/null ; echo $$?); \
    if [ $$K_DESC == 1 ]; then \
        kubectl create namespace $(KUBE_NAMESPACE) \
    else \
        kubectl describe namespace $(KUBE_NAMESPACE) \
    fi
```

Notice that I added a `\` to the end of each line to concatinate them into a single recipe line (so no variables fall out of context).

Or, more quaintly, you could do:

```
namespace: 
    @     kubectl describe namespace $(KUBE_NAMESPACE) > /dev/null 2>&1 \
       || kubectl create namespace $(KUBE_NAMESPACE)
```

Note -- the `> /dev/null 2>&1` will prevent any output (stdout and stderr) from the first command.

Comment: Why would you pass `K_DESC:=$(shell ...)` to the shell? It's `make` code; the shell will just complain about the syntax.

Comment: Sorry, my bad.   Programming in to many languages/scripts these days and getting my syntax mixed up.   Fixed.

Comment: Hi. This is not solving the problems I have. The command inside the K_DESC variable runs fine from within the Makefile. The problem is really, the things I describe. The solution you propose at the end is very elegant, but unfortunately, `kubectl` does output error messages when the namespace doesn't exist, so it doesn't work.

Comment: The command you described would work in the main context of the makefile, but if put in a recipe for a target, then it's interpreted as a shell script, in which case you can't use the spaces (or the `:=` for that matter... overlooked that one -- bash only likes `=`).   So...  what are you trying to do -- are you trying to run this at make read-time or at the point the recipe is invoked?